# AngulaJS Material not working in Android Web View?

Tags: angularjs, android-webview, material-design, angular-material

I have downloaded the sample code of angular.js material , from [here](https://material.angularjs.org/#/getting-started) it is working fine in browser , but when i created a web view for the same in Android its not working or showing a blank screen in my android device
i have tested it in different devices including Samsung galaxy s4 , samsung tab , etc.

Comment: i have already given a link of  mobile angular ui from where i have downloaded the code. [link](https://material.angularjs.org/#/getting-started)

Comment: what version are you using? I think 0.9.0 the last version and fixed most bugs related to mobile devices

Comment: version 0.8.3 , i have read somewhere that angular material and polymer does not suppourt in below 4.4 android version ,have any idea about it? please share ?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to update Latest version of Angular Material Design 0.9.0 Then everything should work. See the bugs related to Android phones and they fixed them 0.9.0 -ver.

https://github.com/angular/material/commit/81bcf7fd15fd76f054814b34d8a877168fc6225c